# Is it possible to use a Fluent NHibernate convention to map all ICollections as sets?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, hashset, automapping

Is it possible to use a Fluent NHibernate convention to map all ICollections as sets? I have an entity like so:

```
public class NoahsArk
{
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    public NoahsArk()
    {
        Animals = new HashSet<Animal>();
    }
}
```

With fluent mappings, this property would be mapped as `HasMany(x => x.Animals).AsSet()`, but how would I do this with a convention that I want to use with the automapper?

I should add that by default, `ICollections` get persisted as `ILists`, and I get a cast exception when it tries to cast the `HashSet` to `IList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible in a convention, currently. If you want the automapper to treat your collections as sets by default, use `ISet` instead of `ICollection`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that was the case. Unfortunately, `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet` directly implements `ICollection` and there's no `ISet`, so it's either go back to lists or use `Iesi.Collections.ISet` with `HashedSet`, but then that couples you to Iesi.

Comment: You're already coupled to Iesi.Collections by using NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

In response to [Christina's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990593/is-it-possible-to-use-a-fluent-nhibernate-convention-to-map-all-icollections-as-s/4782411#4782411), you have to create a new class that implements `IAutoMappingOverride<T>`:

```
public class AlbumOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Album>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Album> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Pictures).AsSet().Inverse();
    }
}
```

Then tell FNH to use it in the configuration:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(...)
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assemblies(...)
        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<Album>()))
    .BuildConfiguration();
```

You'll need a new override class for every entity you need an override for, but it's mostly a copy and paste affair.